# Stubbing function to return something acceptable for .promise()

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jestjs

I'm running tests and I'm stubbing a function that calls the AWS sqs.deleteMessage function.  .promise() is called on the call to this function.  Every time I run my tests with the coverage I notice that it jumps to the catch block thus an error must be occurring on my .promise() call.

I've tried stubbing the function to resolve the promise but that doesn't seem to work.  I've tried returning data as well and still have the same issue.

Below is an example of the code I'm trying to test. It never reaches the logger.info() line

fooObj.js

```
const foo = async (req) => {
  try{
    let res = await bar.deleteMessage(handle).promise();
    logger.info("Sqs result message " + JSON.stringify(res));
  } catch(error){
   #catch block code
  }
}
```

Below is the code for bar.deleteMessage()
bar.js

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const sqs = new aws.SQS();

deleteMessage = function(handle){
  return sqs.deleteMessage({
    ReceiptHandle: handle 
   });
}
```

And finally here is the test code

```
const fooObj = require('foo')
const barObj = require('bar')
jest.mock('bar')

describe('foo test', ()=>{
  test('a test' , ()=>{
    barObj.deleteMessage.mockImplementation(()=>{
      return Promise.resolve({status:200})
    });

    return fooObj.foo(req).then(data=>{
      #Expect statements here
    })
  }
}
```

So I would like the logger.info line to be reached in coverage but I assume the issue has to do with how I'm stubbing the bar.deleteMessage function.  I could use the aws-sdk-mock but I feel like I'm violating unit testing principles by mocking the sqs call that is in another file and the proper way to do it would simply be to properly stub the bar.deletemessage() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need one change:

`bar.deleteMessage` needs to return an *object* with a `promise` *property* set to the function that returns the `Promise`:

```
barObj.deleteMessage.mockImplementation(() => ({
  promise: () => Promise.resolve({ status: 200 })
}));
```

...or you can shorten it to this if you want:

```
barObj.deleteMessage.mockReturnValue({
  promise: () => Promise.resolve({ status: 200 })
});
```

Comment: Saving my butt once again .  For some reason only the first example seems to work for me.  Regardless, thanks!

Comment: @Wollzy glad I can help out :)

Comment: @Wollzy also, it's weird that `mockReturnValue` didn't work...did you copy it in exactly as written above (modified with your actual variable name)?

Comment: No I do not copy it exactly as you wrote it because, as I have done many times in the past, I read too quickly through something and made a mistake.  I didn't even notice the mockReturnValue change.  Adding that to my tool box now.